# What is the value of a parameter with a non-matching select?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

For instance, is the following XSL, called with the following XML, what is the value of 'param'?

The issue is that I need to test for unmatched attributes, and it is apparently not an empty string.

```
<el></el><!-- has no attribute 'attr' to match -->

<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:call-template name="template">
        <xsl:with-param name="param" select="@attr" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="template">
    <xsl:param name="param" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$param" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value will be the *empty node-set*.

You can have a look at the specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#variable-values).

There's a note at the end of this paragraph that also provides a clue:

> NOTE:One convenient way to specify the empty node-set as the default value of a parameter is:
>   `<xsl:param name="x" select="/.."/>`

Since the root node has no parent, this will always return an empty node.

Comment: Any idea how you'd test to see if the param was the empty node set?

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="not($param)" />` should return true if `$param` is the empty node-set.

Comment: @KthProg This is a trick question. A parameter can be empty or not, and it can be a node-set or not.